# How to use search_columns in WP_User_Query?

Tags: users, wp-user-query

I am using `WP_User_Query` to search use by name, ID, email etc...
In that case I need to use `search_columns` field to pass ID or email of user.

What i am doing is

```
$my_users = new WP_User_Query( 
                    array( 
                        'role' => $role,
                        'offset' => $offset ,
                        'number' => $number,
                        'fields' => 'all',
                        'search_columns'=> array( '5','', 'johndoe_dd@yahoo1.com','',''),
                        //'search_columns'=> $search_columns_array,
                        'meta_query' => $meta_query_array,
                    ));
```

For reference  http://wpsmith.net/2012/wp/an-introduction-to-wp_user_query-class/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the link you reference: The `search_columns` attribute does not set what should be searched for in each column, but instead specifies *which* columns should be searched for the term set in 'search'.

Specifically, you can only search for one term - but you can look in one or more columns.

```
//Search user logins & emails for 'foo'.
$my_users = new WP_User_Query( 
              array( 
                'fields' => 'all',
                'search'=>'foo',
                'search_columns'=> array('user_login', 'user_email'),
            ));
```

From the [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-includes/user.php#L480), the default values are:

- `user_email` - if an '@' is present in the search term
- `user_login`, `ID` - if not, but the term is numeric
- `user_url` - if not, but the term looks like an url (and you have less than 10000 users).
- Failing to meet any of the above, it defaults to searching `user_login` and `user_nicename`

The source:

```
$search_columns = array();
if ( $qv['search_columns'] )
    $search_columns = array_intersect( $qv['search_columns'], array( 'ID', 'user_login', 'user_email', 'user_url', 'user_nicename' ) );
if ( ! $search_columns ) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $search, '@') )
        $search_columns = array('user_email');
    elseif ( is_numeric($search) )
        $search_columns = array('user_login', 'ID');
    elseif ( preg_match('|^https?://|', $search) && ! wp_is_large_network( 'users' ) )
        $search_columns = array('user_url');
    else
        $search_columns = array('user_login', 'user_nicename');
}
```